# Operation vectorization in numpy

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I am given an numpy array of dates(date is a number from 0 to 371).

```
dates = [234, 12, 343, ...]
```

and and empty array `date_counter` (of size 372).

```
date_counter = [0, 0, ..., 0]
```

For every date from `dates` I would like to increment `date_counter`. How can I make this operation vectorized?

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of occurrences for value and then update the date counter.

For instance, to get the increment:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(dates, return_counts=True)
```

And then:

```
date_counter[unique] += counts
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `np.histogram` is your friend here. It does exactly what you're asking: counts items and puts them into "buckets". A smaller (human readable) example:

```
In [9]: vals = [9, 0, 1, 2, 2, 9, 3, 7, 8, 9, 9]

In [10]: date_counter, _ = np.histogram(vals, bins=np.arange(11)) # 11 -> 373 for your case

In [11]: date_counter
Out[11]: array([1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Each index corresponds to the number of items with value equal to that of said index (i.e. the last number in `date_counter` is `4`, located at index `9`, meaning there are four `9`s) as desired.

HTH.

Comment: He didn't say that `dates` is of size 372. At least, `bins` has to be equal to `np.arange(373)`.

Comment: @VadimShkaberda Oh yeah, that was a mistake, good catch! It doesn't matter what size the input array is, just matters how many bins you want. In OP's case, it'll be 373.